# How to create a list from panda dataframe rows?

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Series       Level     M1     M2     M3  ...    M10     M11     M12  
0              1      1.0    0.0    0.0  ...   88.08   72.68   88.98   
1              2      1.0    0.0    0.0  ...  151.82  208.64   57.80  
2              3      1.0    0.0    0.0  ...   25.54   12.93   22.29   
3              4      1.0    0.0    0.0  ...   53.74   39.39   20.45   
4              5      1.0    0.0    0.0  ...   83.73   26.72    3.83   
...          ...      ...    ...    ...  ...     ...     ...     ...     
1995        1996      1.0    0.0    0.0  ...   17.74   12.06   38.17   
1996        1997      1.0    0.0    0.0  ...   25.54   12.06   37.81   
1997        1998      1.0    0.0    0.0  ...    1.85    2.19    9.23   
1998        1999      1.0    0.0    0.0  ...  106.06   93.71  108.01  
1999        2000      1.0    0.0    0.0  ...   10.07    7.64    2.73
```

And I want to extract lists like these:

```
list[0] = [1.0    0.0    0.0  ...   88.08   72.68   88.98]
list[1] = [1.0    0.0    0.0  ...  151.82  208.64   57.80]
.
.
.
list[1999] = [1.0    0.0    0.0  ...   10.07    7.64    2.73 ]
```

Comment: So you want a list where each value is the corresponding row in the dataframe?

Comment: If it is a `pandas` dataframe, then you can do `values_list = df.to_numpy().tolist()`

Comment: Avoid looping through Pandas rows. If you have a lot of data, it will be slow. Try to vectorize your operations.

Comment: Something like that @Ozzy08.
I need 2000 list, where they will be the dataframe rows, from M1 to M12 column.

Comment: @CosmeRodolfoSantos Why do you want to do this? Vectorized operations are faster on pandas than with lists.

Comment: Hi @Ozzy08. I am open for new methods.
Do you know any already closed topic that can solve this issue?

Comment: @CosmeRodolfoSantos ywbaeks's answer above does what you are asking. But I want to know why you are doing this because converting the dataframe to a list might not be the most efficient method.

Comment: @Ozzy08, the idea is to plot - in one graph - 2000 lines + the mean value.
So in x axis i would have the twelve Months, and in y axis i would have 2000 values of element list.

Comment: @CosmeRodolfoSantos This can be done with matplotlib. Check out this page: https://www.w3resource.com/graphics/matplotlib/basic/matplotlib-basic-exercise-5.php. In your case, x would be `i in range(1, 13)` representing every month and y would be every corresponding value, which you can find by looping through the dataframe with the `enumerate()` function or just looping through every value in `len(df)` and creating a boolean mask to find each value for that row.